# A Surprising Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

My friend gave me the following series about trigonometric functions:

$$ s(x) := \sin \Biggl( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \, \zeta(4n+2)}{2n+1} \, x^{4n+2} \Biggr) $$

and

$$ c(x) := \cos \Biggl( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \, \zeta(4n+2)}{2n+1} \, x^{4n+2} \Biggr) $$

where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function. Then, $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ seem to converge to the following values

$$ s(x) = \frac{\sin\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr) \cosh\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr) - \cos\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr) \sinh\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr)}{\sqrt{\cosh(\sqrt2\pi x) - \cos(\sqrt2\pi x)}} $$

and

$$ c(x) = \frac{\sin\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr) \cosh\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr) + \cos\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr) \sinh\bigl( \frac{\pi x}{\sqrt2} \bigr)}{\sqrt{\cosh(\sqrt2\pi x) - \cos(\sqrt2\pi x)}} $$

respectively. This series is too transcendental for me to prove. I would like to know the proof of this series, but I can't seem to prove it on my own. Can anyone out there prove this series?

Answer (score 1):

The following calculations can be made rigorous for $|x|<1$ which is the radius of convergence of your original sums. Instead of computing them separately, it's best to join them:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= c(x)+is(x) \\
&= \exp\left(i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\zeta(4n+2)}{2n+1}x^{4n+2}\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\zeta(4n+2)}{2n+1}(ix^2)^{2n+1}\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2n+1}\left(\frac{ix^2}{m^2}\right)^{2n+1}\right) \\
\end{align}
$$
At this stage, it's natural to study the entire series:
$$
A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$$
It's just keeping the odd terms of $-\ln(1-z)$ so:
$$
\begin{align}
A(z) &= -\ln(1-z)+\frac12\ln(1-z^2) \\
&= \frac12\ln\frac{1+z}{1-z}
\end{align}
$$
so you sum is:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \exp\left[\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{ix^2}{m^2}}{1-\frac{ix^2}{m^2}}\right)\right] \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\prod_{m=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{ix^2}{m^2}\right)}{\prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{ix^2}{m^2}\right)}}
\end{align}
To finish, you'll just need to product formula of the trig functions:
$$
\sinh(z) = z\prod_{m=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{z^2}{(\pi m)^2}\right) \\
\sin(z) = z\prod_{m=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{(\pi m)^2}\right) \\
$$
and using the addition formulas you get the final result.

Hope this helps.